# Consume JSON data (asmx) via C# page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, .net-3.5

I have code similar to this:

```
[ScriptService]
public class Titles : WebService
{
    List<Title> Title = new List<Title>();

    SqlConnection connection;
    SqlCommand command;
    SqlDataReader reader;

    [WebMethod()]
    public List<Title> GetTitle()
    {
        var title = new List<Title>();

        using (connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connString"]))
        {
            using (command = new SqlCommand("some query here", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    int col1Index = reader.GetOrdinal("col1");

                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        title.Add(new Title(reader.GetString(col1Index)));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return title;
    }
}
```

I can then use jQuery to get the above code to return XML or JSON, e.g:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/webservices/titles.asmx/GetTitle',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
```

By changing the jQuery dataType and contentType to XML, the webservice above will return XML instead of JSON.

My question is, can I use the above web service in a standard C# asp.net page so I can extract the values and use the values however I want, i.e. something simple like get the webservice to return JSON and then get C# to response.write it to screen?

Comment: by c# page do you refer to aspx or cshtml?

Comment: You can't use C# on the browser side (well you can using Silverlight or etc. but it doesnt count :) you should use JavaScript

Comment: @ChadCarisch, I mean aspx.

Comment: Unless he wants to do server side work. In which case a web service is not needed.

Comment: @ArsenMkrt, can I not get C# to consume the webservice at serverside?

Comment: @ChadCarisch, sorry, I mean't serverside.

Comment: Basically, I already have the webservice which I am using clientside, but I also need to use it on the same data on the serverside.  Instead of me writing the code again, I was hoping to skip a step and just use the existing webservice.

Comment: @ChadCarisch, sure you can... than I didn't understand the question, you can just call it directly, what is the problem than?

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following on the server side

```
var results = (new Titles()).GetTitle();
// do stuff with results.
```

Keep in mind that this is really not the purpose of web services though.

In an aspx file this would like like:

```
<%  var results = (new Titles()).GetTitle(); 
 foreach(var r in results){%>
       <div><!-- do stuff with each item in results --></div>
 <% }%>
```

Comment: Basically, I already have the webservice which I am using clientside, but I also need to use the same data on serverside.  Instead of me writing the code again, I was hoping to skip a step and just use the existing webservice.

Comment: I guess the main thing I don't know is how to get C# aspx to consume the webservice (asmx file) before I can use it as shown in your code example?

Comment: You dont need to consume the asmx as a service. Just use the class that is behind the service.

Comment: I'm being really thick, sorry.  I have an aspx file and I have an asmx file.  I don't understand how to use the code in the asmx file in the aspx file.

Comment: @oshirowanen Are the asmx and aspx in the same project?

Answer (score 0):

ASMX, by default, returns SOAP, which is XML. It does not matter what you ask for, it is not going to be returned.

In the ASP.NET world, you have a wider toolbox. If you want JSON (and XML?) you can use the Web API to return the data. By default, it is JSON, which should work here. There is also some magic in the ASP.NET internals to have a method return data. The core methodology in web forms is AJAX, but you can wire in JQuery, if you like it better. It is all in understanding how dat is returned.

But, with ASMX, you return XML in the form of SOAP. I have seen someone (years ago) take over the internals a bit in web services and return JSON. It was a major kludge. It worked, but I would not advise this when there are a number of ways of solving it without kludging up the internals of ASP.NET.

I would start here: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

It is a simple explanation of how to consume JSON with JQuery in ASP.NET.

Comment: It seems my question was not very clear.  To clarify, I already use that webservice clientside using jquery.  I just wanted to use the same webservice (so I don't have to write similar code again which returns the same data) serverside.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly consume a web service via an .aspx page - the easiest way that I've been able to do this is to use the WebClient object in the System.Net namespace via something like the following code:

```
        WebClient serviceRequest = new WebClient();
        string responseStr = "";
        responseStr = serviceRequest.DownloadString(new Uri("http://www.yourwebserver.com/yourwebservices/YourService.svc/json/getwhateverdatayouneed/" + passInAParameter));
        //I'm not really sure if these next 3 lines are needed, but to deserialize into a Data Table I had to do this string manipulation
        responseStr = responseStr.Replace("\\", "");
        responseStr = responseStr.Replace("\"[", "[");
        responseStr = responseStr.Replace("]\"", "]");
        DataTable dtMyDataFromService = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(responseStr);
```

This example also makes use of the Newtonsoft.Json dll which you can download from  [Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/6.0.3) - this is probably the most popular library for serializing and de-serializng json in .NET.  Assuming your web service returns a STRING (you really don't want to use native .NET data types in JSON-based web services), the code example above will deserialize the results into a .NET Data Table on your .aspx page.  Once you do that, per your question, just loop through the data table and Response.Write it to the screen (you could also write the raw json by just Response.Write(responseStr)).

Hope this helps! - JM